# Are the Precision Energy Recovery and Energy Renewal weapon mods, the same thing?

Tags: control

In-game, they both say "Energy gained from Headshots" and a percentage.

[The Wiki](https://control.fandom.com/wiki/Mods) says that Energy Renewal "Increases energy received from headshots" while "Precision Energy Recovery" increases "Energy gained from Headshots"

Is there a difference? Is "Energy Renewal" always better since it can give higher percentages?

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but if anyone still wants the actual answer:

the lower % one is from the final winning chest after finishing a jukebox/expedition session.

And it’s got a “+”(lower number)% instead of just (bigger number)% like the “inferior” one and what the +% one does is that it increases your maximum energy for a while

so it’s highly rewarding for those exceptionally good at doling out headshots. (Obvious enough but)it works best with spin and grip)

- *protip: Throw the “eternal fire” legendary mod in the mix and you’re
  on the correct path to being a grip fanboy/girl like the rest of us)*

Comment: I'm sorry, this is hard to parse / understand. Could you use the mod names? But I think you're saying that at least one of the mods' descriptions is wrong, if one of them works like the "Energy Boost" Personal Mod which increases max Energy? https://control.fandom.com/wiki/Mods#Energy_Boost